# How delete "Other" files in SD card windows phone

Tags: windows-8.1, sd-card, windows-phone

When I opened Storage Sense from my Lumia mobile, it has a section of other files. And it is saying around 1.3 GB of other files are present and they were not recognized.

It also says, connect mobile to a PC to view and delete. But I don't see any junk files other than my personal music, photos, documents, and other stuff.

Can you please tell me how can I delete such files? I tried to view hidden files too, but with no success.

Is there any application that lists all unidentified files?

Please help me.

Comment: Is all of your music, photos, documents and other stuff accounted for under other headings? WinPhone may just not be recognising all of it and so might be clubbing it under Other Files. You can confirm by using a card reader to view the contents of the SD card on your PC rather than via the connected phone itself.

Comment: Thanks. This is also one  of the strong reason behind this. There are some audio files which were not loaded in music app after I took update for Music app. But Windows Phone OS should move such files to a folder say, Other, so that users can either delete or do some other actions. It just says,other, but it nowhere identifies what are the other files. It should also give an option to delete them from phone itself with a cleanup utility.

Comment: I don't disagree but this is something entirely for Microsoft to address. You can provide feedback for WinPhone 10.